# Need help autoplaying a Spotify embedded iframe

Tags: spotify, autoplay

I've got some quick code here for screwing around - https://jsfiddle.net/qeavdwsj/6/.

In real life, I'm trying to figure out how to trigger an event on the embedded spotify iframe, to autplay a song upon website opening. Right now you have to click on the song to play it - so annoying.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('BUTTON').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.originalTarget) {
        alert("Simulated clickon Target button has orignalTarget");
    }
});

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var e = new Event("click");
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    e.originalTarget = target;
    target.dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a good question. In general it is not possible to modify the content of an `iframe` from another website for security reasons, but there may be a Spotify API to do this.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll check out the API further. I'm curious if it's possible to overlay something over the iframe that could simulate a click? That may be wishful thinking.